# Horizontally aligning multiple divs within a parent section

Tags: html, css

I have a few divs inside a parent section and I'm trying to do an alignment so that the divs are centered within the section.  As they are right now, the divs are left aligned.  I've tried doing `margin: 0 auto` but that's not working.  Can anyone explain how I could accomplish this?

[Pen](http://codepen.io/RobbyT15/pen/xqeoEL)

```css
section {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.notice {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 10vh;
}

section .socialmedia{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 15vh;
}
//The divs I'm trying to center
section .icon{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 15vw;
    height: 15vh;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="notice">
    <h1>Our website is currently undergoing construction, please feel free to contact us on social media.</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="socialmedia">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.socialmedia { text-align: center; }
.icon { display: inline-block; }
```

and remove `float` from the `.icon`.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my code to show the changes you suggested and that it doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBRjYW (btw. // comment in CSS is not valid, see the linked pen).

Comment: It's probably because of the comment I tried then or my cache.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Strangely enough, though, it isn't working on my development version.

Answer (score 1):

just use "margin: 0 auto;" without "text-align:center" and without "display:inline-block;", and without float

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, that doesn't work either.  I've updated the code to show.

Comment: It is working correctly inside your pen now... as vbulant said you have to remove the // comment!